# Split cart in magento according to item

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, order-splitting

I wish to wish split my cart according to the item. At a time I want to checkout with one product.For multiple products, cart will split into multiple carts and user at a time can checkout with one product.

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That’s a tall order and probably well beyond the scope of what can be taught in a post here. That’s a large operation.

Comment: @ShawnAbramson yes I know its a large operation, but I need suggestions how I can start this.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following the below steps.

**Step-1:** When user click in any product checkout button that time you need to save rest product in session and remove from cart. In checkout page, it will charge only single product which the user chooses for checkout.

**Step-2:** After checkout and before the success page load you need to add session product again in the cart.**(use observer for this)**

**Step-3:** After added product in the cart then you need to clear the session again.

**For example,** if a user come back from the checkout page to cart page without placing an order in this case you need to add session products back to the cart and clear session.